# Is non-constant holomorphic map $f:\mathbb P^n\to \mathbb P^n$ surjective?

Tags: complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, several-complex-variables

Let $\mathbb P^n$ denote the $n$-dimensional complex projective space.

From Forster's book **Lectures on Riemann surfaces** p.11, Theorem 2.7, we know any non-constant holomorphic map $f:\mathbb P^1\to \mathbb P^1$ is surjective.

So, similarly, do we have any non-constant holomorphic map $f:\mathbb P^n\to \mathbb P^n$ is surjective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to see this is to use the GAGA principle to establish that $f$ must be algebraic, since it is a map between projective varieties over $\Bbb{C}$. Then, an algebraic map from $\Bbb{P}^n$ to itself is finite or constant. If it is finite, it maps $\Bbb{P}^n$ to a (Zariski) closed subset of $\Bbb{P}^n$ of dimension $n$. Since $\Bbb{P}^n$ is irreducible, this implies that $f(\Bbb{P}^n) = \Bbb{P}^n$ and we have surjectivity.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on "use the GAGA principle to establish that $f$ must be algebraic"? I know that any analytic variety in $\mathbb P^n$ must be algebraic, is this the GAGA principle you mean？

Comment: Essentially, yes. The other important thing is that a map between projective complex manifolds must also be an algebraic map (i.e. holomorphicity is equivalent to being algebraic –– not true for affine varieties for instance).